# Free Software or Online Site to Create Text Pictures / Images (A blank, can be colored, background and text in the middle); Text to Image

Tags: image-editor

This seems to be very simple, yet I can't find what I am looking for. I have found some sites, which I'll mention later, but they have limitations.

I simply want to define a size for an image — a blank background — optionally specify a color background, and to then begin typing text in the center, and ideally to be able to adjust font, font size, and color. The most important part for me is that the text be centered vertically and horizontally in the center of the image (like one can do in Microsoft Word for example, with a large table / large cell in a table in which one has the text centered directly in the middle, both vertically and horizontally).

These are some sites that do some of what I am asking:

https://www.branah.com/text-to-image : This is one of the best ones, but it doesn't center both vertically and horizontally without the right CSS code, which when I found online, it caused the page to be displayed horribly (it didn't render right), and very large also because of the dimensions I specified of 1920 x 1080 (my phone dimensions). The page shows the actual size of the image, so that's partially why, but I think the CSS code interfered with the websites page somehow. I also don't want a phone app (plus I found one that works great) because I can type faster on the computer and it's easier and faster to work with.

http://www.text2image.com/pit_t2i/saver : This one has a dimension limitation, but also, since it's not a live preview, I can't tell if I am running out of space on the image when the text gets very long.

http://www.i2symbol.com/text2image : That one seems to be defective and doesn't do anything. Regardless, I don't see any options for centering or specifying image size.

---

http://interactimage.com/ : And in going over the websites I found lately, I found this one, which is the one I used years ago and gets the job done. There is no dimensions limitation and it does center the text both horizontally and vertically by default but can be changed via the Control Panel option it has if you want to do so. It doesn't let me see the text live so I can't tell if I am running out of space, but I can press create multiple times. Since the image I want is very large, I have to move it to the side so it doesn't cover up everything.

**UPDATE**: There is a text limit of 140 characters.

---

Anyhow, I still would like to know of other sites and software, because I believe there has to be more, as this seems very simple.

I also want the main focus to be on typing, so two steps procedures like doing this in word and then taking screenshots, are not solutions I am looking for. After I have everything setup (background color, font size, dimensions of image, and so on), I just want to type away or copy and paste, and then save. Also, other programs can do all that I am asking, including the centering, but I must manually center the box or change its dimensions if I for example made it small and then have lots of text later on. I want the centering to be done automatically. Like I said I just want the typing or pasting of text to be the main thing I am doing.

I look forward to your recommendations and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of tools for the job. [Canva.com](http://canva.com) is one and [Stencil.com](https://getstencil.com?tap_a=9103-1801f8&tap_s=273684-2d447a) is another.

Hope they are fit for you. =)